# reading in a file line by line - where is the file?

Tags: c, macos, terminal

Im new to using GNU C by using Terminal on a Mac.

I've used a standard piece of code to read in a file line by line and referring out to a file by "file.txt".

I can compile the source but when I execute the code it can't find file.txt. I have put the file in the the same directory as the source and executable file. Should I be adding a full directory path. I tried :-

"/Users/Swiss/documents/swdev/projects/code_ex/file.txt"

but that comes up with the same error as just using "file.txt".

The error I get is:-

-bash: ./read_file.lbl: No such file or directory

and am assuming its the file.txt it can't find - or is it something else?

The code is:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
   static const char filename[] =  "/Users/Swiss/documents/swdev/projects/code_ex/file.txt";
   FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
   if ( file != NULL )
   {
      char line [ 128 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
      while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
      {
         fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
      }
      fclose ( file );
   }
   else
   {
      perror ( filename ); /* why didn't the file open? */
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Any help will be warmly welcomed.

Comment: Where's your code? Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: The error message you posted says it can't find read_file.lbl, not file.txt.  How exactly are you running your compiled program?

Comment: At the command line:- to compile - MBP:code_ex Swiss$ make read_file_lbl and to run ./read_file_lbl

Comment: @SwissT Where do the name 'read_file.lbl' come from ? Also please answer the question of dbush', **how are you running**  should be answered by you copy pasting the command you are running. (And you should also show us how you compile/link your program)

Comment: @SwissT That doesn't tell us anything useful.  **How** are you running from the command line, i.e. what command are you giving to run it?

Comment: Also, what command are you using to compile?

Comment: not - read_file_lbl is the filename i called the .c file (shortened read file line by line). dbush -  commands I used are as above.

Comment: @SwissT please edit your question and tell us following: the exact name of the C source file (e.g `myprog.c`), the command you launch to compile your program (e.g `gcc myprog.c`), and finally the command you type to launch your program (e.g. `./a.out`).

Comment: The error message is coming from the shell, not your program.  It says  you're trying to run ./read_file.lbl when the executable is named ./read_file_lbl

Comment: Michael Walz

The exact name of the source file is:  read_file_lbl.c

To compile the program I used: make read_file_lbl

To run/launch i used: ./read_file.lbl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is correct. If the source file is called `read_file_lbl.c`, run these commands to compile it and run it from the terminal:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o read_file_lbl read_file_lbl.c
$ ./read_file_lbl
```

If you compile the program with `gcc read_file_lbl.c`, the compiler names the executable `a.out`, so trying to run `./read_file_lbl` fails as no such executable is found by the shell.

Note also that `gcc` is really a link to `clang` on your environment. You can check with:

```
$ gcc --version
```

Comment: Thank you all. I need to be clearer about my questions in future. Thank you for you help.

Comment: @SwissT: no problem, one learns to walk by making the first steps... You can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.